# How can write text in OPENGL window at c#

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I want to know , how can i write texts in opengl window using C#? I use opentk tools for drawing, I would pleased for anyone to tell me what code I must use in C#.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to render a text using opentk you should consider many thing. you can go to [OpenTK Docs](http://www.opentk.com/doc) to find out. but I recommend you to use [QuickFont](http://www.opentk.com/node/2823) instead, without going into the complicated details.

good luck